# Objective-C, Constructing a String, code review

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

This code works fine, but each time i look at it, i die a little bit inside. :(

Can you help me streamline it a bit?

Is there a more elegant way to .append(SomeString)? (To give you some perspective, code prints elements of the Linked List)

```
- (NSString *) description {      
    Node* tempNode = [self firstNode];

    if (tempNode == nil) {
        return @"List contains no elements";
    }

    NSString *desc= [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"(null) -- "];
    desc = [desc stringByAppendingString:[firstNode nodeCharacter]];
    desc = [desc stringByAppendingString:@" -- "];

    while ([tempNode nextNode] != nil) {
        desc =  [desc stringByAppendingString:[[tempNode nextNode]nodeCharacter]];
        desc =  [desc stringByAppendingString:@" -- "];
        tempNode = [tempNode nextNode];
    }

    return [desc stringByAppendingString:@" (null)"];


}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you don't like. However for multiple appends why you don't use NSMutableString?

Comment: stringByAppendingFormat makes two lines redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First of all, if you want to build a string step by step or modify it, **stop using `stringByAppendingString:`**, and **use `NSMutableString`** instead of `NSString` !!!
- Then, for your matter, you can even use `stringWithFormat:` to build part of your string.
- Finally, you forgot to manage your memory: you alloc/init your string but never release it (and as your reassign the `desc` variable the line after, you loose track of the allocated memory and have a leak.

So here is the revised code:

```
- (NSString *) description {      
  Node* tempNode = [self firstNode];

  if (tempNode == nil) {
    return @"List contains no elements";
  }

  NSMutableString *desc = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"(null) -- %@ -- ",[firstNode nodeCharacter]];
  while ((tempNode = [tempNode nextNode]) != nil) {
    [desc appendFormat:@"%@ -- ",[tempNode nodeCharacter]];
  }
  [desc appendingString:@" (null)"];

  return desc;
}
```

*(Note that you may also build an NSArray of the nodes of your list and use `componentsJoinedByString` then at the end… so you have multiple possibilities here anyway)*

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [NSMutableString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)? It has -appendString: methods.

**Edit:** You could also use a recursive function on your node to traverse the list and build up the string. I would make some simple public method like `- (NSString *)description` to call the first method and then use a private method internally to do your dirty work, like so:

```
- (NSString *)recursiveDescriptionWithSubnode:(Node *)node {
    if(!node) {
        return [self nodeCharacter];
    }
    else {
        return [[self nodeCharacter] stringByAppendingString:[self recursiveDescriptionWithSubnode:[self nextNode]];
    }
}
```

Note that this isn't tail recursive and so for a long list this would build up a sizable autorelease pool and call stack. Making it tail recursive is left as an exercise for the reader (but you could use `NSMutableString` to do it).

Answer (score 1):

Yes use an `NSMutableString` which will involve much less memory allocations.

```
- (NSString *) description {      
    Node* tempNode = [self firstNode];
    if (tempNode == nil) {
        return @"List contains no elements";
    }

    //Autorelease string to prevent memory leak
    NSMutableString *desc= [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"(null) -- "];
    [desc appendString:[firstNode nodeCharacter]];
    [desc appendString:@" -- "];

    while ([tempNode nextNode] != nil) {
        [desc appendString:[[tempNode nextNode]nodeCharacter]];
        [desc appendString:@" -- "];
        tempNode = [tempNode nextNode];
    }

    [desc appendString:@" (null)"];
    return desc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the while loop, take a look at Cocoa's [Fast Enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH18). It is supported by NSArrays already, and allow you to rapidly enumerate through array elements:

```
for (id object in myArray)
    // Do something with object
```

You can adopt fast enumeration (or use NSEnumerator) in your node elements, then loop through them:

```
// Use mutable strings
NSMutableString *desc = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"(null) -- "];
for (Node *node in nodeList) {
    [desc appendString:[node nodeCharacter];
    [desc appendString:@" -- "];
}
return [desc stringByAppendingString:@" (null)"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building up a string, you could create an array of strings, that you ultimately return as a single, joined string separating each value with your " -- " string.

If you know how many elements you might have, you could create the array with that capacity, which might be slightly more efficient under the hood for NSMutableArray.